# assigning button to search for computer files in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How would you code a button to bring up a search of files on the Mac, so the user can select a file? This program will require the user to choose which file he is going to send to an external device.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the [NSOpenPanel class?](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use the `NSOpenPanel` ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) to allow the user to select a file.

You use it like this:

```
NSOpenPanel *openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
// Configure the panel if necessary using openPanel.whatever = something;
NSInteger result = [openPanel runModal];
if (result == NSOKButton)
{
    NSURL *url = openPanel.URL;
    NSAssert(url.isFileURL, @"Expected a file!");
    NSString *filename = url.path;
}
```